# How would I write this typedef enum from objective c to swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Below, I have the objective-c code which is used for tinder style animation effect , inspired by - https://github.com/ngutman/TinderLikeAnimations/tree/master/TinderLikeAnimations .

**Objective-c**

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger , GGOverlayViewMode) {
    GGOverlayViewModeLeft,
    GGOverlayViewModeRight
};

- (void)setMode:(GGOverlayViewMode)mode
{
    if (_mode == mode) return;

    _mode = mode;
    if (mode == GGOverlayViewModeLeft) {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1"];
    } else {
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2"];
    }
}
```

I am trying to replicate the same in swift. This is what I have in swift -

```
enum GGOverlayViewMode : Int {
    case GGOverlayViewModeLeft
    case GGOverlayViewModeRight
}

    func setMode(mode: GGOverlayViewMode){
//        if (_ mode == mode) {
//            return
//        }
//
//        _mode = mode;

        if(mode == GGOverlayViewMode.GGOverlayViewModeLeft) {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button1")
        } else {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button2")
        }
    }
```

But somehow its not making sense to how would I be handling the typdefs here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are not required to `typedef` `enum`s in swift; you just define them like you have done. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Your implementation looks complete. You should not expect there exists  a one-to-one mapping between swift and obj-c keywords

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Swift each [enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_221) has its own member values, so you don't have to give
them a unique prefix as in (Objective-)C. A typical definition would be

```
enum GGOverlayViewMode  {
    case Left
    case Right
}
```

Also you don't have to specify an underlying "raw type" (such as `Int`), unless
you have other reasons to do so.

Instead of a custom setter method you would implement a [*property observer*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_390).
`didSet` is called immediately after the new value is stored, and has an implicit
parameter `oldValue` containing the old property value:

```
var mode : GGOverlayViewMode = .Right {
    didSet {
        if mode != oldValue {
            switch mode {
            case .Left : 
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button1")
            case .Right:
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in swift, your function will look like this.

```
enum GGOverlayViewMode : Int 
{
case GGOverlayViewModeLeft
case GGOverlayViewModeRight
}

func setMode(mode: GGOverlayViewMode){
switch mode
{
  case .GGOverlayViewModeLeft:
  imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button1")
  case .GGOverlayViewModeRight:
  imageView.image = UIImage(named: "button2")
}
}
```